# Difference in Sessions data in GTM vs GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I found 10% high number of sessions in the GTM analyitcs data than the GA. Both has different tracking properties, have similar settings(as Simoahava mentioned @[here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/4nrX0SfbL7Q)), Hence the Ecommenrce rate is affecting due to huge difference of sesions data in both properties. Any insights ?

Screenshots : 
[Session via GTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1er4D.png)       [Session via GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmUF5.png)

Comment: With GTM you mean sending hit via GTM vs on page GA code?

Comment: @Tushar Yes Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Even when out of scope for the question i need to advice you to remove the legacy UA code from site and just duplicate the hits from GTM. (Simo has a post about it)

Now going into the question it self this can have a couple of reasons:

- Does the filters on both views match?
- Does both views has the same region (on the config)?

And i have another theory but this is not at all checked. (i would like to look into it)
GTM has a noscript snippet which allows to send non-script dependent tags even when javascript is not enabled. This is an advantage against the old GA code which doent have this feature.
Point i may have to look into:

- Does the pageview count as a non-script dependent tag?
- Is the traffic without javascript that relevant in volume? (10% is a lot)

Hope it helps !